# Switching to an new activity by clicking on pop up menu item using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

```
 class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_favourite:

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_play_next:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is my code please somone suggest how can i switch the activity using intent instead of showing the toast.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntendedActivity.class); // pass necessary context
startActivity(intent);
```

Check this link for all that you can do:
[Start Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add intent call for your next activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```